# Setting up virtual host

Tags: apache2, virtualhost

I currently have all my websites as directories under `/var/www`. I would like to set up a virtual host `http://foo/` that points to the `/var/www/foo/foo` directory (and still keep the default localhost behavior).

I added the following file, `foo`, to `/etc/apache2/sites-available/`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName foo
    DocumentRoot /var/www/foo/foo

    # Other directives here
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/foo/foo>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I then ran the following commands:

```
sudo a2ensite foo
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 reload
```

But when I go to `http://foo/` it still returns an ISP search page.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to edit your `/etc/hosts` file so that `http://foo` resolves to 127.0.0.1.

Edit the file `/etc/hosts` (with sudo/root) and add the following line:

```
127.0.0.1 foo
```

Answer (score 1):

Checkout https://github.com/Aslamkv/vh :)

This tool lets you add and remove virtualhost in Ubuntu by doing every configuration for you. It is simple and easy to use.

Disclaimer: **I am the author :P**

Answer (score 0):

For those using apache. You will need to

```
Ensure you have .htaccess in root path of the site you are hosting. Example /var/www
Update the /etc/apache2/sites-available/default
```

From

```
<Directory /var/www/>
 Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
 AllowOverride None
 Order allow,deny
 allow from all
</Directory>
```

To

```
<Directory /var/www/>
 Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
 AllowOverride All
 Order allow,deny
 allow from all
</Directory>
```

Hope this helps someone

Comment: Shouldn't the 2 `directory` blocks be different?

Answer (score 0):

If you wish, you can have a look at the answer I've posted here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12532263/apache-domain-for-localhost-to-access-folders-as-http-folder-local/12563570#12563570