# Virtual Hosts Not Working (12.10)

Tags: apache2, virtualhost

I'm trying to get virtual hosts up and running on my Ubuntu laptop that has 12.10 installed. I'm running Apache2, and I enabled the virtual hosting module.

When I go to 12.0.0.1, I'm able to get the default page.  When I go to example.local, I just get the search engine results, instead of the "hey, you're seeing this" page I set up in that directory (/var/www/example.local).

I even made sure I have only one "NameVirtualHost *:80" variable active. Checking error.log, nothing obvious seems to jump out as being amiss.  here's what I have in the respective files:

**example.local**

ServerName example.local
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/example.local
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/example.local>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>

ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
<Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
LogLevel warn

CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

**ports.conf**

NameVirtualHost *:80
Listen 80

**hosts**

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   KitaiGorod

127.0.0.1       example.local

::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Comment: Okay . . . when I do this: w3m http://example.local, I get the customized content that I had put into the index.html file.  So, it seems to be up and running through terminal, just not on the web browser. I'm puzzled . . .

Comment: Well, mysteriously, it's now working in my browser once I entered this into the browser window: http://example.local

Case closed.  Really odd, though.

Answer (score 1):

It seems `example.local` is a simple file in `/var/www`, not a new virtual host. Check the reference to vhost [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/128658/setting-up-virtual-host)